# Rails multiple master keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have multiple rails apps running on a production box, is it possible to have multiple environment variables?

What we have now in .bashrc is

```
RAILS_MASTER_KEY="secret"
```

Can we do something like

RAILS_KEY_1="secret1"
RAILS_KEY_2="secret2"

and then in config/environments/production.rb

do something like

```
config.secret_key=ENV["RAILS_KEY_1"]
```

Is there any mechanism in rails to support multiple master keys?

Thanks,
kevin

Comment: Which Rails version?

Comment: You can provide the key via a `master.key` file instead of an env var. Thats probally your best bet unless you want to use per folder env vars with something like DirEnv or a preloader like Foreman to invoke the rails commands with a different `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` env var.

Comment: right but then you have to commit master.key to the repo right?